# Why are the first four bytes of the Java class file format CAFEBABE?

Tags: java

Why are the first four bytes of the Java class file format **CAFEBABE**?
Who named it?

Your views/guesses?

Source: [IBM Java Programing Dynamics](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429/)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28file_format%29#Magic_Number

Answer (score 130, accepted):

James Gosling, the father of Java programming language, once explained it as follows:

> As far as I know, I'm the guilty party on this one.  I was totally unaware of the NeXT connection.  The small number of interesting HEX words is probably the source of the match.  As for the derivation of the use of `CAFEBABE` in Java, it's somewhat circuitous:
>
> We used to go to lunch at a place called St Michael's Alley. According to local legend, in the deep dark past, the Grateful Dead used to perform there before they made it big. It was a pretty funky place that was definitely a Grateful Dead Kinda Place. When Jerry died, they even put up a little Buddhist-esque shrine. When we used to go there, we referred to the place as Cafe Dead.
>
> Somewhere along the line it was noticed that this was a HEX number. I was re-vamping some file format code and needed a couple of magic numbers: one for the persistent object file, and one for classes. I used `CAFEDEAD` for the object file format, and in grepping for 4 character hex words that fit after `CAFE` (it seemed to be a good theme) I hit on `BABE` and decided to use it.
>
> At that time, it didn't seem terribly important or destined to go anywhere but the trash-can of history. So `CAFEBABE` became the class file format, and `CAFEDEAD` was the persistent object format. But the persistent object facility went away, and along with it went the use of `CAFEDEAD` - it was eventually replaced by RMI.

#### Source:

- [Wikipedia/Class (file format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28file_format%29#Magic_Number)
- [Bill Bumgarner blog entry: `0xCAFEBABE & 0xFEEDFACE`](http://radio-weblogs.com/0100490/2003/01/28.html)

#### Somewhat related links

- [Hex words](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/hexwords.html) and [upside down words](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/HexWords.htm)

Comment: Awww. He missed out on the opportunity to do `CAFEFEED`. (OK, not perfect as it involves a repeated byte…)

Comment: @DonalFellows you mean `CAFEDEAD` and not `CAFEFEED` right?

Comment: If I recall correctly, early MacOS (pre OS-X) used `0xDEADBEEF` for invalid pointers (or handles, perhaps).