# How to recognize a generated .class file programatically?

Tags: java, .class-file, generated-code

I am developing an application that analyzes Java applications (Windup).
I'd like to be able to recognize programatically if a .class file was generated instead of written by a programmer and compiled.

As a human, I can tell because the decompiled code doesn't make much sense. It looks a bit like some kind of java-ish mix of C.

I could somehow implement recognizing the resulting decompiled code.
However, decompilation takes time, I'd like to skip decompiling for generated classes.

For more information on what is a generated .class file, see [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/bytecode-libraries).

Is there a way to recognize generated .class just from headers? Or perhaps some specific bytecode sequence?

Comment: [detect the CAFE BABE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2808646/1065197)

Comment: What do you mean by "generated"? All .class files are generated, by the Java compiler. Do you mean you want to detect if the Java code that is the source of the .class file was generated by a tool instead of a developer? There is no way to make such a disctinction.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean. Do you want to detect if the .class file was recompiled in the last compilation and contains the latest changes?

Comment: No, not CAFE BABE. That recognizes any .class file. Compiler doesn't generate, it compiles. Generators generate.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, any legal class file starts with the magic numbers `0xCAFEBABE` as it is [specified by the JVMS §4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html). The simple fact that a file starts with this magic number does however not guarantee you that the file represents a compiled Java class, as anybody is able to create such a file.

Reading between the lines of your question, I assume that you want to find out if a class was generated by *javac* or another compiler / runtime code generator. This is not possible to determine as anybody can imitate *javac* as close as possible. As a matter of fact, many runtime code generators try to imitate the *javac* compiler as closely as possible as it can lead to performance improvements as the JIT-compiler recognizes some patterns that are typically used by *javac*.

If the code that you want to analyze derives a lot from "usual Java code", you can look for [byte code patterns that are not representable in the Java language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827363/bytecode-features-not-available-in-the-java-language/23218472#23218472). This way, you can prove that a class was not generated by *javac* but you cannot generally proof that it was generated by it.

Answer (score 1):

Java Classfiles always begin with the magic bytes `CAFEBABE`. If you want to recognize classfiles, that's the best way to do it.

If that's not what you want, you'll have to clarify the question.

Comment: No, not any .class file. But generated class files. See various java class generators like Rational etc.